# while accessing remote database which is in different timezone i'm not able to find the last 10 min records

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.1

I want last 10 min records from database for that i have used this query

```
select * from x_table where x_time >=(now()-interval '10 minutes')
```

I'm accessing this remote server which is in different time zone from local machine and 11 hrs behind the my time

so when i'm trying the given query is not giving me correct output

what i can change in query so that i'll get the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

If you know it's always going to be 11 hrs behind, just subtract another interval.

```
select * 
from x_table 
where x_time >=(now() -
                interval '10 minutes' -
                interval '11 hours')
```